# libcurl - runtime exception with x32 DLLs

Tags: c++, curl, dll, runtime-error, libcurl

I've downloaded curl from `http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/` (direct link to archive, no installer). And I put the `libcurl.lib` from `curl-7.45.0-win32\lib` into Visual Studio 2015 project and compiled it. It worked fine (I use x64 Windows 10, but the project is x86).

Then I put the DLLs files from `curl-7.45.0-win32\dlls`:
[image]

But when I run the program (from Visual Studio, debug mode) and I got the runtime error:

> Exception thrown at 0x52874918 (libcurl.dll) in MyProgram.exe 0xC00000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

When I put x64 DLLs from `curl-7.45.0-win64\dlls` it says that program has not been start correctly. And without DLLs program warns me that it couldn't find them.

So I guess the DLLs from `curl-7.45.0-win32\dlls` are the right ones, **but what I do wrong here?**

I am almost sure the program was working few days ago.

Only things I've changed in project settings (from default) are:

1. Character Set: Use Unicode Character Set
2. Runtime Library: Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)

The source code that I added to test the curl is based on one of their samples (inside `test.cpp`):

```
bool Test::test(...){
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
std::string readBuffer;
std::string userPassword = C::toString(login + L":" + password); 

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(!curl){ ERROR(L"CURL could not been inited."); }
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, userPassword); //e.g.: "user:password"
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl); //here I get an exception
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

return res == 0;
}
```

And the `WriteCallback` is defined in `Test.h`:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <curl/curl.h>

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
return size * nmemb;
}

class Test {
public:
    bool test(...);
}
```

Comment: Let me hazard a guess. The error is somewhere in your code!

Comment: @n.m. I thought it is related to the version of DLLs or something, as the source code is based on curl sample. I've extended the question with the source code.

Comment: I would recommend to build your own version of libcurl in debug mode and use the debugger on it.

Comment: I'll second that suggestion. The combination Windows and binary downloaded DLLs is a can of worms just asking to get problems like this due to memory models, compiler conventions and more. libcurl is fully open and quite easy to build yourself to circumvent this kind of problem.